# CSS float won't work?

Tags: css, css-float

My menu is currently under the logo, but instead I want it to be horizontal to the logo. I think the `float` property is the only way to do something like this(?) but it doesn't work, it won't float.

```
#top_menu {
height: 20px;
color: #333;
position: relative;
float: right;
}

#top_menu ul li {
        float: left;
        color:#333;
        padding-right:15px;
        font-family: Tahoma, Helvetica, sans-serif;
        font-size:11px;
    }

        #top_menu ul li a {
            text-decoration:none;
            color: #666;
            padding: 1px;
            padding-right: 8px;
        }

                #top_menu ul li a:hover {
                    color:#f2e9c9;
                }
#logo{
    margin-top: 15px;
    width: 200px;
    height: 30px;
    position: relative;
    right: 5px;
}

        <div id="logo"><a href="http://www.playcreatividad.com/es/index.php"><img src="logot.png" alt="lolly"></a></div>
    <div id="top_menu">
        <ul>
          <li><a href="http://www.playcreatividad.com/es/index.php" title="Enlace a Portada">Portada</a>|</li>
          <li><a href="http://www.playcreatividad.com/es/equipo.php" title="Enlace a Equipo">Equipo</a>|</li>
          <li><a href="http://www.playcreatividad.com/es/workbook.php" title="Enlace a Workbook">Workbook</a>|</li>
          <li><a href="http://www.playcreatividad.com/es/frescologia.php" title="Enlace a Frescología">Frescología</a>|</li>
          <li><a href="http://www.playcreatividad.com/es/clientes.php" title="Enlace a Clientes">Clientes</a>|</li>
          <li><a href="http://playsaid.blogspot.com/" target="_blank" title="Enlace a Blog">Blog</a>|</li>
          <li><a href="http://www.playcreatividad.com/es/noticias.php" title="Enlace a Noticias">Noticias</a></li>
        </ul>

</div>
```

What's wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand correctly you want the Logo and the Menu on the same horizontal line. If that is the case you can:

1. Float the logo to the left OR

   ```
   #logo{
       margin-top: 15px;
       width: 200px;
       height: 30px;
       position: relative;
       right: 5px;
           float:left;
   }
   ```
2. Display the logo as inline-block

   ```
   #logo{
       margin-top: 15px;
       width: 200px;
       height: 30px;
       position: relative;
       right: 5px;
           display:inline-block;
   }
   ```

Comment: Inline-block is not much cross-browser.

Answer (score 0):

Put the logo div after the top_menu div.